# Questions migrated away from us still appear

Tags: discussion

The recent questions about [a just and merciful god](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/1313/is-the-christian-god-just-and-or-merciful-evangelicals-if-any-please-go-first) does seem more appropriate to christianity.SE, because there is little general theological philosophy in the question.

But it still appears on phil.SE (with the additional '[migrated]').

Shouldn't it just disappear from here? (and possibly similar reasoning would justify appearance or not for '[closed]')

Comment: Migrated is a special status; I'll go ahead and delete the question, but in general I think leaving closed questions undeleted is good (as long as they are not profane or something) as they help new members get a sense of our topicality line.

Answer (score 3):

The primary purpose of closing - and migration falls into this as well, to an extent - is to provide the author and others with an opportunity to salvage a question that might otherwise be deleted.

Deleting straight away would also be confusing to users who returned unable to find the question they'd asked, with no indication that it had ever existed much less why it might have been removed.

If this doesn't happen, they will probably end up being deleted at some later time (in this particular instance, Joseph has taken care of this). Once deleted, links to migrated questions redirect automatically to the question on the site migrated to.

Comment: More and more I'm finding that the nominal purposes of voting and closing and such are more an more removed from how they are actually used. Deletion removes a question altogether. Closing is more like a slightly different kind of down-vote threshold. Regular questions and closed questions still 'fall off the radar', just closed questions have a little less opportunity to be bumped.

Comment: @Mitch: well, folks not making use of the feature is why some of us spend our days surfing the metas evangelizing it; some sites make more use of it than others (and some sites have more *need* of it than others). For a young site like this one, there are still few enough users who *can* edit/close/reopen/delete that you'll see less of the process than you will on more established sites.